# swap jquery backgroundColor for background image?

Tags: jquery, css

A friend gave me a solution that uses this jquery code:

```
.css({ backgroundColor: '#ddd' })
```

Instead, i'd like to use a background image.  How do I change the jquery code to do that?

I'm wanting to do something like

```
.css({ backgroundImg: 'images/newsletter-dropdown.jpg' })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy as pie:

```
$( element ).css({ 'background-color': 'transparent', 'background-image': 'images/newsletter-dropdown.jpg' });
```

Comment: hmm-doesn't work for me.  Image property is getting dropped in firebug as well...

Comment: I ended up finding a way to do it through css. That said, I still marked your answer as correct. Thanks!